# Is there a way to launch .exe files added to the solution

Tags: c#, console-application, executable

I have a console app that needs to be able to launch an executable file that is a WPF application. The two applications are linked through files but are independent applications. I just need to be able to execute one from the other. My problem is I need the path of the EXE to be consistent or dynamic so that when someone else uses it the file can still be found so I tried to embed the exe.

I have tried (project -> add -> existing item -> add the exe) then configure it to an embedded resource. However when I execute the code Process.Start("WebViewSolution.exe"); it says that the file isn't found even though it shows in the solution.

```
            if (innerResponse.ToUpper() == "OPEN EXTERNAL PROGRAM")
            {
                Process.Start("WebViewSolution.exe");
            }
```

Because I added the file as an embedded resource I thought that it could launch with only the file name. If I save the program to my desktop I can launch it using the path to the desktop no problem. However the desktop is specific to my computer.

Comment: Is it being copied to the output directory? (Check Properties -> Copy to Output Directory)

Comment: yes, when I add copy to output directory, I no longer get the error about the file not being found, however the exe does not execute. A WPF window should appear but I just get a spinning cursor

Comment: Is `Process.Start` returning `false`? Or is it hanging/not even returning?

Comment: how do you check if it is returning false?

Comment: The application that is supposed to start isn't appearing in Task Manager at all either leading me to think it's not even starting at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the Build Action of `WebViewSolution.exe` to 'None' and Copy to Output Directory to 'Copy if newer'
2. Verify that your current directory is pointing to the correct location. `Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());` Because the current directory might change at runtime, I tend to avoid relative paths and rather use something like `Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "WebViewSolution.exe")`
3. Verify that `WebViewSolution.exe` successfully starts when you manually start it from windows explorer.

`var ps = Process.Start("WebViewSolution.exe");
Console.WriteLine(ps.HasExited);`

Comment: So the current directory does appear in the bin\debug. However on starting the application, it returns False and the application still doesn't execute.

Comment: and for what you said about verifying if it does run from windows explorer. If I have the exe on my desktop I can launch it successfully. However, as soon as I move it into the solution and then find the file in the repo on my computer, it no longer executes. So that I guess is the problem, but it creates a whole new problem haha.

Comment: I found the problem, all of the other files contained in the application folder had to be present as well. They all had to be switched to "copy if newer" as well. Thanks for the help!